# Regex to match string at certain position

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am new to regex. I have a file on Linux with below data. I want to replace the string at position 5th, 7th, 8th .
I am able to replace the data using the below command

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS="|" 'NR>1 {$5="testdata-1" ; print ;}' testfile > testfileawk.csv
```

Is there a way to keep the header from the original file in new generated file?

Example:

`"JD"` will be replaced with `"XYZ"`, `"Nic"` will be replaced with `"PQR"`
`"KLIN"` will be replaced with `"XYZ"` , `"JO"` will be replaced with `"PQR"`, `"TUCK"` will be replaced with `"ABC"` and so on
Header and footer values will be copied to new file without any modifications
Is there an easy way to accomplish this in UNIX using sed command?

Below is the data from the file:

```
Header|Names|20200717|some text
"15025"|"Legal"||"tenant_004"|"JD"|1|"NIC"||||
"11057"|"Legal"||"tenant_004"|"KLIN"|1|"JO"|"TUCK"|||
"3200"|"Legal"||"tenant_004"|"FF 2081 test LLC"|1|||||
"4100"|"Legal"||"tenant_004"|"PQL JKP TRUST"|1|||||
"1105"|"Legal"||"tenant_004"|"Nick"|1|"St"|"Pierre"||"JR."|
TRAILER|2045678
```

Comment: Sed isn't a good choice for this; awk would be much better suited.

Comment: @AnnZen You changed the contents of the file...? There was an edit before yours that modified the first column.

Comment: @BenjaminW. What did I change?

Comment: @AnnZen The first column was changed to just four digits, and you accidentally rolled it back

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sorry, I'm confused. Can you please edit it back?

Comment: @AnnZen It's in revision 3 – and I doesn't really matter for the question itself anyway.

Comment: Thank you guys, I am open to use awk.

Comment: You should make an attempt using awk, then, and post specific problem you've encountered.

Comment: I updated the question. I am now able to get data using awk that I wan to replace. I am not sure, how to go about replacing the data

Comment: Do you have a file or something with all the replacement pairs?

Comment: you should keep search and replacement terms in a separate file

Comment: Updated my question again. I am now able to replace the data. Now I need to figure out how to keep the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="|"
}
NR > 1 && $1 != "TRAILER" {
   $5 = "testdata-1"
}
1' testfile > testfileawk.csv
```

Note that using `1` in the end will print each record including header.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. How can we modify that code to also skip the footer?

Comment: Thanks. But that didnt work. It removed the footer. I think I worded my question wrongly before may be. By skip I meant, copy over the footer to new output file, skip the data updates on footer.

Comment: Can you edit question and show sample data with expected output

Comment: I have added header and footer in my question. The output file will hve the same header and footer as the input file.

Comment: ok try this: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR > 1 && $1 != "TRAILER" { $5 = "testdata-1" } 1' file`